# Record Html Css3 animation as video

Tags: javascript, html

I have created html div with some basic slides of texts and animations with background audios.Basically its a full screen webpage that just looks like a video.

Now can I export this as a video.I searched in stackoverflow and came across 
https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-fromelement/#html-media-element-media-capture-extensions

But I really do not understand anything from that link.How do I start the function to record video ? and then export the stream.All I found is following code.Do I pass my Html ID here ? I am very new to js , please be gentle.

```
partial interface HTMLMediaElement {
    MediaStream captureStream();
};
```